# Navigating into a folder with random generated name using the ftp command 'mput'

Tags: batch-file, file-upload, ftp, command

I have a script which is generating a folder with a random name and 4 characters long.
Every folder also has a static extension, in this case ".backup".

For example: The random generated foldername + extension is "h8Re.backup".
I want to copy the data inside the folder to my ftp server.

I tried it with the following mput command (works with the 'cd' in cmd, but not with mput):

```
mput "C:\Users\Username\Data\*.backup\*"
```

Here's the short code of the batch:

```
open ftp-server.de
username
password
cd ftp/backup
prompt
mput "C:\Users\Username\Data\*.backup\*"
bye
```

While mput can copy all data inside a folder with *, it seems like navigating to folders using * is not possible?
Since the first 4 characters will change everytime, I need to work with the extension I guess.

Please note, the folder has also subfolders, I dont want to copy the data in the subfolders.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, as with all other Windows commands, filemask is supported only for filenames, not for other path components.

If I understand your question correctly, you know the folder name, so use it in your script.

```
echo open ftp-server.de>ftp.txt
echo username>>ftp.txt
echo password>>ftp.txt
echo cd ftp/backup>>ftp.txt
echo prompt>>ftp.txt
echo mput C:\Users\Username\Data\%UNIQUE%.backup\*>>ftp.txt
echo bye>>ftp.txt
ftp -s:ftp.txt
```

(assuming you have the generated name in variable `%UNIQUE%`).